# Posting ajax variables on click

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor link as follows:

```
<a class="show-next-page" id="10" href="#" name="category" rel="100000">
```

And here is the click handler:

```
$('.show-next-page').click(function(){
    var prodId = $(this).attr("id");
    var catId = $(this).attr("rel");
    var type = $(this).attr("name");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin-catalog/next',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "catId=" + catId + "&prodId=" + prodId,
        success: ajaxCatProds
    });

    return false;
});
```

As you can see, I am attaching lots of data to this anchor link, but I am beginning to run out of "valid" attributes to attach more data to. I am now beginning to think that this may not be the correct way to be doing this.

Can anyone advise an alternative / more elegant method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using data attributes.

HTML

```
<a class="show-next-page" data-id="10" href="#" data-name="category" data-rel="100000">
```

JS

```
//This method will give all the data attributes associated with the element.
var dataAttrib = $(this).data();
var data = {
    //You access the data attribute with there name without data part
    prodId: dataAttrib.id,
    catId: dataAttrib.rel,
    type: dataAttrib.name
};

$.ajax({
        url: 'admin-catalog/next',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: ajaxCatProds
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into jQuery's [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/). Description as stated in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified
>   element. Returns the value that was set.

**Example Set:**

```
$.data("[YourElementID]", 'categoryID', 52);
```

**Example Get:**

```
var catID = $.data("[YourElementSelector]", 'categoryID');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use custom attributes, using the `data-` naming convention.  (e.g. `data-amount`, `data-dataTypeID`, etc.).

jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function is also aware of these named attributes and can access them without the `data-` prefix.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.show-next-page').click(function(){
    var prodId = $(this).attr("id");
    var catId = $(this).attr("rel");
    var type = $(this).attr("name");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin-catalog/next',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'catId':catId ,'prodId':prodId,'type': type},
    });

    return false;
});
```